# In a query (no editing of tables) how do I join data without any similarities?

Tags: sql, oracle

I Have a query that finds a table, here's an example one.

```
Name |Age |Hair   |Happy | Sad |
Jon  | 15 | Black |NULL  | NULL|
Kyle | 18 |Blonde |YES   |NULL |
Brad | 17 | Blue  |NULL  |YES  |
```

Name and age come from one table in a database, hair color comes from a second which is joined, and happy and sad come from a third table.My goal would be to make the first line of the chart like this:

```
Name |Age |Hair  |Happy |Sad |
Jon  | 15 |Black |Yes   |Yes |
```

Basically I want to get rid of the rows under the first and get the non NULL data joined to the right. The problem is that there is no column where the Yes values are on the Jon row, so I have no idea how to get them there. Any suggestions?

PS. With the data I am using I can't just put a 'YES' in the 'Jon' row and call it a day, I would need to find the specific value from the lower rows and somehow get that value in the boxes that are NULL.

Comment: I am a beginner with SQL and any help is appreciated!

Comment: search about inner join

Comment: "get rid of the rows under the first": `select * from ... where Name = 'Jon'`. Or `select * from ... where rownum = 1 order by ...`

Comment: How are tables joined? This would be essential in order to suggest a proper solution.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes pretty sure `ROWNUM` is meant to be used with `ORDER BY` you know that SQL tables/resultset are defined to **orderless**, not using `ORDER BY` for sure results into non deterministic ("random") results..  But ORDER BY on non unique values can still result into non deterministic ("random") as well, ideally a column with PRIMARY/UNIQUE  KEY should be added in the ORDER BY to make it always deterministic ("fixed")

Comment: From what I read an OUTER JOIN in combination with NVLs would work.

Comment: Yes, the question is very unclear. Is "first row" meant as an example for data or literally the first row? It could also be `where Happy is null and Sad is null` or something else.

Comment: to add to @OlivierJacot-Descombes on this data example we can't say what the "first row" is /means as there is no defined order..

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes with the actual data I am using the first row is fixed due to my WHERE statement being specific using IN. Also, the other rows are fixed along with the values for happy and sad.

Comment: If no ORDER BY is specified, the order of the rows is not defined, i.e., if the Oracle suddenly changes the execution plan because there are more rows in the tables, the same query could return the rows in a different order. The WHERE clause defines which rows appear, but not in which order.

Comment: You must see the answer of this simat question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57515150/move-non-null-values-up-within-partition

Comment: What happens if the lower rows contain YES and NO and NULL? What sense does it make to apply the values of Kyle and Brad to Jon? If would however make sense to `GROUP BY Name` and then to apply an aggregate like `SELECT MAX(Happy) ...`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the sense is that in my real data the yes under the other names will be a number of a piece of equipment. I want the numbers of the equipment in one row instead of having like 8 rows with only 4 ' yes' values and the rest null. Apologies for this being an unclear post I do not know too much about this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join on a NULL value work with nested selects. The inner select gets an Id for NULLs, the outer select joins

```
select COALESCE(x.Happy, yn_table.description) as happy, ...
from
    (select
        t1.Happy,
        CASE WHEN t1.Happy is null THEN 1 END as happy_id
    from t1 ...) x
    left join yn_table
        on x.xhappy_id = yn_table.id
```

If you apply an `ORDER BY` to the query, you can then select the first row relative to this order with `WHERE rownum = 1`. If you don't apply an ORDER BY, then the order is random.

---

After reading your new comment...

> the sense is that in my real data the yes under the other names will be a number of a piece of equipment. I want the numbers of the equipment in one row instead of having like 8 rows with only 4 ' yes' values and the rest null.

... I come to the conclusion that this a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

You are asking about a detail you think will solve your problem, instead of explaining the problem and asking how to solve it.

If you want to store several pieces of equipment per person, you need three tables.

You need a `Person` table, an `Article` table and a junction table relating articles to persons to equip them. Let's call this table `Equipment`.

```
Person
------
PersonId (Primary Key)
Name
optional attributes like age, hair color

Article
-------
ArticleId (Primary Key)
Description
optional attributes like weight, color etc.

Equipment
---------
PersonId (Primary Key, Foreign Key to table Person)
ArticleId (Primary Key, Foreign Key to table Article)
Quantity (optional, if each person can have only one of each article, we don't need this)
```

Let's say we have

```
Person: PersonId | Name
            1    | Jon
            2    | Kyle
            3    | Brad

Article: ArticleId | Description
            1      | Hat
            2      | Bottle
            3      | Bag
            4      | Camera
            5      | Shoes

Equipment: PersonId | ArticleId | Quantity
               1    |    1      |    1
               1    |    4      |    1
               1    |    5      |    1
               2    |    3      |    2
               2    |    4      |    1
```

Now Jon has a hat, a camera and shoes. Kyle has 2 bags and one camera. Brad has nothing.

You can query the persons and their equipment like this

```
SELECT
    p.PersonId, p.Name, a.ArticleId, a.Description AS Equipment, e.Quantity
FROM
    Person p
    LEFT JOIN Equipment e
        ON p.PersonId = e.PersonId
    LEFT JOIN Article a
        ON e.ArticleId = a.ArticleId
ORDER BY p.Name, a.Description
```

The result will be

```
PersonId | Name | ArticleId | Equipment | Quantity
---------+------+-----------+-----------+---------
    3    | Brad |   NULL    |    NULL   |  NULL
    1    | Jon  |    4      | Camera    |    1
    1    | Jon  |    1      | Hat       |    1
    1    | Jon  |    5      | Shoes     |    1
    2    | Kyle |    3      | Bag       |    2
    2    | Kyle |    4      | Camera    |    1
```

See example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e05d/2/0

Answer (score 2):

Do you just want `COALESCE()`?

```
COALESCE(Happy, 'Yes') as happy
```

`COALESCE()` replaces a `NULL` value with another value.

Comment: Seems like a good solution but with the real data I'm using the "yes" is a specific data point that I need to find and can't just change

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with the oracle tag, you could just use [NVL()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm), which allows you to specify a value that would replace a NULL value in the column you select from.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the 1st row because it contains the smallest age:
- wrap your query inside a CTE 
- in another CTE get the 1st row of the query 
- in another CTE get the max values of `Happy` and `Sad` of your query (for your sample data they both are `'YES'`)
- cross join the last 2 CTEs.

```
with 
  cte as (
    <your query here>
  ),
  firstrow as (
    select name, age, hair from cte
    order by age
    fetch first row only
  ),
  maxs as (
    select max(happy) happy, max(sad) sad
    from cte
  )
select f.*, m.*
from firstrow f cross join maxs m
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT A.Name,
       A.Age,
       B.Hair,
       C.Happy,
       C.Sad
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.Name = B.Name
INNER JOIN C
ON A.Name = B.Name
```

(Assuming that Name is the key columns in the 3 tables)